# is there any way to have Facebook or Twitter update in the background on my iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, facebook

I have an iPod touch.  I want to know if there is any way to have my Facebook or Twitter feeds update in the background?

I often grab my iPod from my home (with WiFi) and then go into the train (no WiFi) and want to see what was posted recently or when I was sleeping.

It seems like these apps only do a "fetch" once you start the app up.

Is there any work around for this so it's always updating if i am on a WiFi network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either leave one of the apps open at night so it will refresh or get something like Boxcar, which would be a solution more fitting to your needs. Boxcar will push notifications from facebook and Twitter, and then you can launch Boxcar to see the updates.